# Deserialize problem for timestamp in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, post

We have webpage in our project where website post the XML data to.

```
string data = string.Concat("XMLParameter=", SampleXML, "&", "AccessCode=", "XYZ");
if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    Response.Write(tmp);
}
```

When we pass following XML with post,

```
<notification timestamp="2009-09-11T11:51:07+02:00">
    <reservation creation_date="2010-09-10T12:03:13">
    </reservation>
</notification>
```

On the receiving end in our web page, timestamp we receive do not contain +. Instead of +, it gives us Space charactor. So, while deserializing it, we got error.

We get the data in page using Request.Form["XMLParameter"]

Any solution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a funny service where the XML data is posted as if it were coming from an HTML form with a text field containing the XML data.

As a consequence, the web server expects your data to be URL encoded. You even tell in the content type that it's encoded. But it isn't. You don't encode it anywhere in your code.

So if you want to stick with your funny service, then you need to run your XML data through *HttpUtility.UrlEncode* first.

Comment: Codo, it seems to be funny but it is not. Actually we are making web services for integration with other websites. But some of the older website or php sites are using POST to send data to us. And you know it is hard to force them to use web service :P. Anyway, sorry if I could not write the explaination that clears perfectly what I wanted. But I think I should try with this and go ahead with third party to send us sample and see if it is coming url encoded or not? Is there any option if they are nt sending url encoded :P. As i said i could not change them :)

Comment: They have to send it URL encoded. Otherwise you won't be able to split the data into the parameters XMLParameter and AccessCode. It shouldn't be too difficult to achieve in PHP as it contains the built-in function _urlencode_.

Comment: Yes. but I dont know what they are using as they are third party people. They just told us that they will send us post data and given above format. Let me talk to them and see whats their response. I think they should pass urlencoded as per your answer.